# Dictionary is returning false on ContainsKey after item is added

Tags: c#, dictionary, containskey

I have a dictionary declared as follows

```
IDictionary<string, object> _objectIds = new Dictionary<string, object>();
```

I was experiencing some problems with it and it discovered that the instance returned false as a result of ContainsKey method and from the watch window I was sure that the item was there.
So I created helper method

```
private bool IdsContainsKey(string key)
{
  lock (syncObject)
  {
     lock (_objectIds)
     {
       if (_objectIds.ContainsKey(key))
         return true; // A
       if (_objectIds.ContainsKey(key))
         return true; // B
       return _objectIds.ContainsKey(key); // C
     }
  }
}
```

During my debugging session I run into situation when the method exited in place B and sometimes I made to C returning true.
Can anybody help me?
Thanks.

Comment: well, that will depend entirely what you pass in!

Comment: well, it doesn't, key as parameter is not mutable and if you follow the code and my question, it is strange that first condition is not met, while the second is and sometimes it is not met too. And result is true.

Answer (score 5):

You need to make sure you put a `lock` around every place you use `_objectIds` in order to be sure you are synchronizing properly.

Comment: well, lock on syncObject is placed everywhere, in fact I pass a wrapper dictionary, that is recording each access or method call to inner dictionary and there are records for only one thread only

Comment: Why is a lock on `_objectIds` required if access to that object is already protected by a lock on `syncObject`? I don't see the value in having a double-lock pattern here.

Comment: I admit that this lock is redundant but I didn't know what to do, so I tried everything including this...

Answer (score 0):

Is there a reason for locking twice? I think

```
private bool IdsContainsKey(string key)
{
  lock (syncObject)
  {
    ...
  }
}
```

should do it. Althought I read somewhere that it's never a good idea to lock the instance with itself.

Comment: But I am not locking the instance itself.

Comment: Sure you do. "lock (_objectIds)" is locking the calls on an instance with itself.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the `lock(_objectIds)` block. Also, why are you using a wrapper dictionary? Since you are using a generic `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>`, you should derive your own custom dictionary and implement your tracking there. Finally, your code would be better written as:

```
private bool IdsContainsKey(string key) 
{ 
   lock (syncObject) 
   {
      return _objectIds.ContainsKey(key); 
   } 
}
```

The result of the method is going to be entirely dependent upon the value you pass in as `key`. I suspect the problems you are encountering are due to incorrect locking in other places, an issue with your wrapper dictionary, or you aren't passing in the key you think you are.

Comment: Wrapper dictionary is used for diagnostic purpose only. I can assure you that every method of the class that contains _objectIds dictionary is "secured" with lock section and _objectIds is declared as private.